# is code sharing between react and react native possible?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, hybrid-mobile-app

I want to know whether, is it possible to create an app which works both on web and mobile app with same code. I think it is possible in angular 2 ionic. But, I'm not sure about react. Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Datamodel, state, helpers etc. yes. Not the code that generates UI. DOM components are different from native components.

Comment: You need to know that Ionic uses webviews so, you can display "anything" web related, but that's an hybrid app.
RN let you write in javascript, apps that are indistinguishable from an app built using Objective-C or Java.
But to answer your question "React Native for Web" might be what you are searching for. 
But in my opinion, in most of cases, it would be wrong to do one "universal" app, cause by design you will be forced to do too much conditionnel rendering and functions and to me it affects the clarity, fitness, .. of the code.

Comment: Have a look at [Code sharing between React and React Native applications](http://ihor.burlachenko.com/code-sharing-between-react-and-react-native-applications/)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible, with help with [react-web](https://github.com/taobaofed/react-web) or [react-native-web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web). But I wouldn't recommend these.